# Using Nz() in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to use VBA to create a form button that affects change on a field MasterInventory.QuantityOnHand.  It works except for a bug that happens when my button is clicked before a value is entered.  I'm trying to use Nz(), but for some reason my placement or something is off.  Please assist.

```
____________________________________________

Private Sub AddBtn_Click()
      
    
    Nz (Me.quantityEntered)
    Me.QuantityOnHand = Me.QuantityOnHand + Me.quantityEntered
    Me.AddBtn.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub quantityEntered_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Nz (Me.quantityEntered)


End Sub 

______________________________________________
```

This is what I've tried so far.  Thank you.

Comment: `something = Nz(Me.quantityEntered)`, `Me.QuantityOnHand = Me.QuantityOnHand + Nz(Me.quantityEntered,0)`

Comment: Saving aggregate data is usually bad design. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: Also, study the documentation on [Nz](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.nz?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: @June7. Thank you. I understand from your reply on aggregate data from my last question that was similar, I think. This is another option I'm working out. This inventory database is not very large in size. Less than 1000 records. That's why I am considering this saving aggregate data approach. Alternatively, I'm going to work on a form that will show these subtotals individually as I navigate from record to record. This wouldn't be considered saving aggregate data right? Also, could I create a query in the same way?

Comment: If you are calculating subtotals to show on form, then that is certainly not saving aggregate data. A database with less than 1000 records would be very unusual - are these aggregate data records? I am not sure what you mean by 'create a query in the same way' - a query that shows individual records as well as subtotals? Yes, that can be done.

Comment: @June7. Yes my project is specifically for an experiential lab that I work in. A side project my boss wanted in order to get us involved in different aspects of engineering. Our projects are also functional improvements on the lab. So what I'm working with is basically an inventory of consumables in a store room and also the equipment in the lab in order to automate. Very small. My calculation is just for tracking current levels of any one consumable. I tried doing this through queries but couldn't figure it out. Forms though I think I can. Having it in forms is my end goal anyway really.

Comment: If you don't want to keep track of supplies and equipment movement with transaction records and simply adjust the totals, that is an option. Just be aware of its deficiencies as far as data integrity.

Comment: @June7 I do have a transaction table that I've built. I thought of using it in a sub form with my master inventory where the changes I make in the sub form will update my master inventory record on a case by case basis.

Comment: Again, that is saving aggregate data when it could be calculated as needed from transaction records.

Comment: Maybe, Gustav was being too subtle?  Nz  works by substituting in a default value or equivalent expression when a Null value occurs. The value you substitute depends on your business case but for any time of inventory I recommend 0.  NZ(me.quantityEntered,0) then since adding or subtracting 0 is weird you can test for adding 0 and respond in a fashion appropriate to your business case.  maybe a pop-up message box asking them to confirm for instance.

Comment: @mazoula.  Thank you.  I tested this code out with the add button and it's worked so far for add function.  I'll move on to subtract and override now.